# How to configure PHP-FPM to run Joomla without setting $live_site in configuration.php

Tags: php, server-configuration

I've spent a good few hours ploughing through code and setting up servers to test exactly what is goes on to cause Joomla to fail in PHP-FPM unless $live_site is correctly set.

The problem turns out to be that when $live_site is empty, Joomla will in most cases rely on the value of the PHP super global $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']. In the case of a site that is installed into the document root, this will be empty when PHP is running as an Apache module, even when the URL is something like https://example.com/heading/article. (Because the actual script is the index.php in the document root).

However, if PHP is running as PHP-FPM (which is a favoured solution for high performance and for site security) then the super global will contain "/heading/article" for the example above. With this value, Joomla does not work out how to handle the request and gives a 404 error.

This can obviously be fixed by hacking Joomla, but that isn't a good solution. Is there any way to make PHP-FPM behave in the same way as PHP as an Apache module? Unless a solution is available, my feeling is that Joomla should continue to support the use of $live_site and fix problems that occur when it is set (notably in Joomla upgrades).